# Combining 2 different queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

I have 2 queries, that I would like to combine into 1. However, I'm getting an error:

```
//first query:
SELECT
  @rownum := @rownum +1 `index`
  , t. *
FROM ipAll t, ( SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r

//second query:

SELECT DISTINCT
  COUNT( ip )
  , SUM( views )
  , DATE
FROM ipAll
WHERE date LIKE '%-12-%'
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC
LIMIT 31

// combined query: (Totally wrong. How do I fix this?)

 SELECT
  @rownum := @rownum +1 `index`
  , DISTINCT COUNT( ip )
  , SUM( views )
  , DATE
FROM ipAll t, ( SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
WHERE date LIKE '%-12-%'
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC
LIMIT 31
```

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Can you give an example of the result of these two queries? ANd how you want those results merged?

In MySQL, there is a UNION statement, which will merge the results of multiple queries. However, the result needs to have the same columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend removing `distinct`.

Let's assume your table had the following content:

```
|                         dt |      ip | views |
|----------------------------|---------|-------|
| December, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 1.1.1.1 |   100 |
| December, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 2.2.2.2 |    10 |
| December, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 3.3.3.3 |     4 |
| December, 01 2014 00:00:00 | 1.1.1.1 |   100 |
| November, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 1.1.1.1 |     1 |
| November, 01 2015 00:00:00 | 2.2.2.2 |     2 |
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
@rownum := @rownum +1 `index`,
COUNT( ip ), SUM( views ) , dt 
FROM ipAll,  ( SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r 
WHERE dt LIKE '%-12-%' 
GROUP BY dt 
ORDER BY dt ASC 
LIMIT 31;
```

will result in:

```
| index | COUNT( ip ) | SUM( views ) |                         dt |
|-------|-------------|--------------|----------------------------|
|     3 |           1 |          100 | December, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|     1 |           2 |          110 | December, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|     2 |           1 |            4 | December, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
```

An alternate way of getting similar (not identical) results is:

```
select @rownum := @rownum +1 `index`, main.*
from ( SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r, (
  SELECT COUNT( ip ), SUM( views ) , dt 
  FROM ipAll
  WHERE dt LIKE '%-12-%' 
  GROUP BY dt 
  LIMIT 31
) main
ORDER BY dt ASC
```

results of which will be:

```
| index | COUNT( ip ) | SUM( views ) |                         dt |
|-------|-------------|--------------|----------------------------|
|     1 |           1 |          100 | December, 01 2014 00:00:00 |
|     2 |           2 |          110 | December, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|     3 |           1 |            4 | December, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beb98/3

Comment: Very good. Confused me with the column named dt for a second there, before I realized it was short for date.